# ASP.NET core installation on mac

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core-1.0

I was installing ASP.NET core on mac os (El Capitan). And after the installation of the .net core SDK. dotnet command in terminal is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you downloaded the SDK from the official link
    https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=827526

**Known issues**

1. ere is link to list of known
       issues: https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/cli/known-issues.md,     I encountered one because I was using ZSH.
2. This might help as well
   https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/cli/known-issues.md